# Sass mixin and loop with percentage symbol print a sassError: Expected identifier

Tags: loops, sass, percentage, mixins

I'm trying to generate a simple sass mixin for `widths`. This could be the expected result:

```
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
.w-50 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

**The problem:** It seems that Sass is not accepting the percentage symbol (%) at the following mixin:

```
$widthCollection: 50, 100;
@each $widthValue in $widthCollection {
  .width-#{$widthValue} {
    width: #{$widthValue}%;
  }
}
```

**Alternatives:**
Adding this symbol to the collection (p.e: `$widthCollection: 25%, 50%`) is not a solution... it also fails.

BUT! You can pass the symbol as a variable like this:

```
$widthCollection: 25, 50, 75, 100;
$symbol: '%';
@each $widthValue in $widthCollection {
  .width-#{$widthValue} {
    width: #{$widthValue}+$symbol;
  }
}
```

Althoguht I've found the solution, I'd like to check if someone knows a better solution or the reason why (%) is not accepted by sass. I'm using a similar mixin for rotation which includes `deg` without any problem. Example:

```
$degrees: 0, 45, 90, 180;
@each $degree in $degrees {
  .rotate-#{$degree} {
    transform: rotate(#{$degree}deg);
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I believe that it tries to interpretate the symbol, you could do `#{'%'}` instead of `%`. Or simply: `$widthValue * 1%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give a solution... both alternatives work perfectly:

**Alternative 1**

Given by @Amaury Hanser

```
$widthCollection: 25, 50, 75, 100;
@each $widthValue in $widthCollection {
  .width-#{$widthValue} {
    width: #{$widthValue}#{'%'};
  }
}
```

**Alternative 2**

Given at the question

```
$widthCollection: 25, 50, 75, 100;
$symbol: '%';
@each $widthValue in $widthCollection {
  .width-#{$widthValue} {
    width: #{$widthValue}+$symbol;
  }
}
```

Thank you!!